# Can I use inter-type declaration to add a property?

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

We have domain objects that extend an abstract base class to support a timestamp

```
abstract class TimestampedObject {
    private Date timestamp;
    public Date getTimestamp(){return timestamp;}
    public void setTimestamp(final Date timestamp){this.timestamp = timestamp;}
}
```

But this clutters our hierarchy.

Could we use Spring AOP introductions or Aspectj ITDs to achieve this ?

Comment: Please provide more detail. Would a custom data type work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is [exactly what ITDs are for](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#inter-type-declarations).

Comment: As a general rule, Spring only does AOP stuff that can be done with interface-based JDK dynamic proxying, so while you might get it to do a method introduction, field introductions are out. You'll have to use AspectJ for that.

Answer (score 1):

An example right out of the AspectJ in Action book (from memory not tested) would go something like this:

```
public interface Timestamped {
   long getTimestamp();
   void setTimestamp();

   public static interface Impl extends Timestamped {
        public static aspect Implementation {
              private long Timestamped.Impl.timestamp;
              public long Timestamped.Impl.getTimestamp(){ return timestamp; }
              public void Timestamped.Impl.setTimestamp(long in) { timestamp = in; }
        }          
   }

   //and then your classes would use it like this:
   public class SomeClass implements Timestamped.Impl {

           private void someFunc() {
              setTimestamp(12);
              long t = getTimestamp();
           }
    }
```

Not sure if the book had it that way or not but I usually create a separate Impl interface (as shown above) that just extends the main one so that some of my classes can implement timestamping differently without acquiring the ITD implementation. Like so :

```
public class SomeOtherClass implements Timestamped {
       private long myOwnPreciousTimestamp;

       public long getTimestamp() {
            //Oh! I don't know should I give it to you?!
            //I know, I will only give you a half of my timestamp
            return myOwnPreciousTimestamp/2;
       }

       //etc.....
}
```

Comment: I just found an answer on my another question in your code. Thanks. +1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139924/cannot-override-method-and-cannot-access-field-while-using-idiom-providing-a-def/7145375#7145375